# How to check string with array of strings in java?

Tags: java

HI I want to check one string value with an array of strings. I am using the `contains()` method, but it is case sensitive. For example:

```
String str="one";
String [] items= {"ONE","TWO","THREE"};

str.contains(items); // it is returning false.
```

Now the question is how to check that string ?

can anyone help me?

thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think you can call `str.contains(items)`, because `String.contains` needs a character array, not a String array.

Answer (score 8):

You probably want to know if *items* contain *str*? And be case-insensitive. So loop through the array:

```
boolean contains = false;
for (String item : items) {
    if (str.equalsIgnoreCase(item)) {
        contains = true;
        break; // No need to look further.
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you could sort the string first using `stringArray=Arrays.sort(stringArray);` you can then use the Binary Search algorithm `int pos = Arrays.binarySearch(stringArray, stringItem);`. `if (pos > -1)` then you found the element else the `stringItem` doesnot exist in the `stringArray`.

Answer (score 1):

If you will only check once:

```
    String str="one"; String [] items= {"ONE","TWO","THREE"};

    for(String s : items){
        if(s.compareToIgnoreCase(str) == 0){
            System.out.println("match");
        }
    }
```

If you will do many checks:

```
    String str="one"; String [] items= {"ONE","TWO","THREE"};

    List<String> lowerItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String s : items)
        lowerItems.add(s.toLowerCase());

    if(lowerItems.contains(str))
        System.out.println("match");
```