# How to check if String contains any of the strings in List/Array

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, contains

I currently have a an ASP.Net Website. This website retrieves RSS-Feeds from different Sources and outputs its own `RSS-Feed`. But is the article contains some word they must be 'blacked out' (Censorship as you might say). The words are contained in a `blacklist` managed by that ASP.Net Website.

My current solution:

```
foreach (SyndicationItem rssItem in syndFeed.Items.OrderByDescending(x => x.PublishDate).ToList())
{
    //if is on blacklist
    bool isValid = true;
    foreach (String blacklistItem in MyBlacklist)
    {
        if(rssItem.Title.Text.contains(blacklistItem))
            isValid = false;
        if(rssItem.Summary.Text.contains(blacklistItem))
            isValid = false;
    }

    if (isValid)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("item");

        //Write Elements
        writer.WriteElementString("PubDate", rssItem.PublishDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
        writer.WriteElementString("title", rssItem.Title.Text);
        writer.WriteElementString("description", rssItem.Summary.Text);
        writer.WriteElementString("link", rssItem.Id.ToString());

        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
}
```

**Question:** Is there a more performant way to do this search? How can i write the following code more simple using LINQ/ Any other Stringoperations?

```
    foreach (String blacklistItem in MyBlacklist)
    {
        if(rssItem.Title.Text.contains(blacklistItem))
            isValid = false;
        if(rssItem.Summary.Text.contains(blacklistItem))
            isValid = false;
    }
```

Based on the following examples from Java:

[Checking if a string contains any of the strings in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703454/checking-if-a-string-contains-any-of-the-strings-in-an-array)

[How to check string with array of strings in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881979/how-to-check-string-with-array-of-strings-in-java)

[Test if a string contains any of the strings from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992100/test-if-a-string-contains-any-of-the-strings-from-an-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
bool isValid = !myBlackList.Any(s=> rssItem.Title.Text.contains(s) || rssItem.Summary.Text.Contains(s))
```

Or

```
bool isValid = myBlackList.All(s=> !rssItem.Title.Text.Contains(s) && !rssItem.Summary.Text.Contains(s))
```

Comment: Oh God! how could i have missed this? Your solution works like a charm! Thanks for the help!